# Server part of ssh tunnel fails to detect client closed connection

Tags: ssh

I am using an ssh tunnel for port forwarding via the command `ssh -fN -R *:443:localhost:443 <public server>`
Sometimes, the ssh process on the client dies (presumably connection timeout), so I have set up a script that tries to reconnect to the server. However, this sometimes fails, as the corresponding `sshd` process on the server lives on and occupies the port despite the fact that the connection died.
I want the server process to detect this and die as well. I have tried adding the following lines to the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to no avail:

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

With these settings, I would expect the server process to die within two minutes of the client process dying, but it's still going some 10 minutes after. When I ran `netstat -p` on it, the tunnel connection looks like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0  18584 <Hostname>:ssh          <ip>:54208              ESTABLISHED 962/sshd: root
```

Is there anything else besides the `ClientAlive` settings I can do to make sure the server process detects the dropped connection and dies as well, freeing up the port for connection reestablishment?

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for sshd_config, `TCPKeepAlive yes` is supposed to ensure that

> the server will notice if the network goes down or the client host crashes.  This avoids infinitely hanging sessions.

The value of this is `yes` by default though. Did you happen to set it to `no`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's only present in `sshd_config` as a comment with the default value of `yes`, so unless sshd also loads config from another file, that's not it.